# Calling a view from a static html page

Tags: django

This is my static html page:

```
<a href="{% url 'studyup/login' %}"><button class="w3-btn w3-light-green w3-large w3-ripple w3-text-shadow">Login</button></a>
```

I'm trying to call a view with url: studyup/login

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', views.loginform_view, name='loginform_view'),
]
```

How to do so?

Comment: that's not a static html page that's a django template

Comment: That's my static html page, I'm actually wondering if there was any way to call a view (like we do in django templates)

Comment: If it truly were static then you'd need the actual url and not the template tag, calling the view isnt the issue here

Comment: I repeat __that's not a static html page that's a django template__ you don't call a anything from a static html page. But you can have links to web pages from them.

Comment: Okay, But if I write **<a href="studyup/login.html"><button class="w3-btn w3-light-green w3-large w3-ripple w3-text-shadow">Login</button></a>**, it searches for a static page with the url studyup/login.html, not the view.

Comment: Because the url that you've defined in urls.py is "/login/", not "login.html".

Comment: href should match a url in urls.py file,not a html file.studyup/login will not match ^login/$ in urls.py.    Go through django tutorials.Atleast first 4 parts.Its really helpful!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of "static" is:

> lacking in movement, action, or change, especially in an undesirable or uninteresting way.

The url template tag is designed to perform an action which goes against this - so your template as shown isn't static. So if you really need a "static" html file. Use the actual url, (maybe even the absolute url depending on your usage)

```
<a href="/login/">
```